# Problem while running a server in django basic app

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have to started to learn django and I'm facing a problem on starting a localhost.
the error I have got is:-

```
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Example>py manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0637DC90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.app'
```

And the error in my code is the include statement shown below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

if you know the solution then please help....

Comment: You have to include the page app in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

Just Include your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `Settings.py` file.Your server is not getting your app and causing the problem.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'pages'
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: I have mentioned the above code but it's saying that path('', include('pages.urls')), NameError: name 'include' is not defined in my code from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('', include('pages.urls')), ]

Comment: @EmranulHaque did you import "include" from **django.urls** ?
     ex : from django.urls import path,include

Comment: Oops I think I forgot to add include.. thanks a lot now it's working

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your app in "INSTALLED_APPS" in settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'pages']
```

Comment: I have mentioned the above code but it's saying that                                  `path('', include('pages.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined`             in my code                            `from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]`

Comment: Import this in that file
**from django.conf.urls import include**